# Computer super slow and laggy, while resources are not being used

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, performance, lag, interrupts

Ok so I have a custom built PC; specs below:

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-4700
Motherboard: MSI Z97-G55
RAM: 16GB DDR3
Video Card: PNY nVidia GTX 770
Primary Hard Disk: Samsung 850 Evo
Primary OS: Windows 8.1
```

For some reason, only semi-recently my computer has been super laggy and jittery. I have never seen a computer this bad since my days with Windows 98. Even with my CPU running at around 20% tops, only 30% of my RAM, and the hard disk is not being used, my computer is SUPER slow. For example, my mouse lags across the screen after a "freeze" delay. I have scanned my computer for viruses and malware and found nothing. I have been monitoring task manager and resource monitor with nothing.

I first noticed this issue when listening to music or watching a video. I also noticed that it only occurred when my network (Realtek ethernet on MB) was being utilized. Online results kept telling me it was my network driver, so I uninstalled it and found no improvement (if anything, it got worst). I have done countless searching online without any luck and now come to all you geniuses for help :).

And to clarify, all this is with pretty much nothing running, no games or anything.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do before I rip my hair out?

<s>**PROBLEM SOLVED:**</s>
Thank you Nathanial Meek for your suggestion to disable the network controller in the BIOS. I did that and the issue went away. I am using an old USB wireless adapter for now until my new network interface card arrives. Thank you all for your help and suggestions!

**UPDATE**:
So I did purchase a decent Intel network adapter and the problem was fixed. However, now a month later the lagging and shuddering is becoming worst and worst everyday, and its all whenever the network is active. I have uninstalled the old drivers, installed new ones, ran many different virus scanners and malware detectors with no luck. I am completely perplexed. This should not be happening! Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Did you install all the latest drivers from each component manufacturer's site or just let Windows Update do its thing?

Comment: @Karan Yes I thought as well and have manually re-installed as many drivers as I could. All drivers are the latest versions.

Comment: How much free space is on the hard drive?? SSD's need 15-25% free space to perform at peak.

Comment: @Moab I have about 60% of the drive free.

Comment: What does SysInternals [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) tell you about your computer's resource use? In particular I'm curious to know how much CPU is consumed by the Interrupts "process".

Comment: @Twisty Thank you for your response. During the shudders, my CPU usage stays about the same with no significant change.

Comment: Is your BIOS up to date?

Comment: @harrymc Yes my BIOS is at the latest version.

Comment: For a custom built PC, there is always the possibility of a hardware problem. Run as many tests as you can find, starting with memory.

Comment: Does the lagging occur if you run another OS on the same hardware? For example, boot with a [Knoppix Live CD](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) and use the system long enough for the behavior to occur.  If it *does* then you know you have faulty hardware.  If it *doesn't* then you should focus on faulty software.

Comment: What software starts at boot? What about services in general? Run services.msc and see if there's anything that you can set to Manual or Disabled, help yourself with Black Viper's famous Windows services page.

Comment: @derpoholic Thanks for your response, I do have quite a bit of services running but they all checked out and anything i did not know of or did not need I disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Windows 7:

Open Task Manager and verify that CPU and RAM are not terribly maxed out for some reason. Click on the Performance Tab and click Resource Monitor. Navigate to the Disk tab and expand Storage. Post Active Time and Disk Queue. It is well known that the Samsung 850 EVO has firmware issues so I'd strongly recommend making sure that your copy of Samsung Magician is updated and you have it run a firmware update on the drive.

Barring that, onboard components can have a serious impact on the stability and performance of a system (Proud owner of 2x ASUS Crosshair 4 Extreme motherboards, if that means anything to you. If not, They had a tendency to bluescreen under any amount of network traffic back when they first came out.). I'd recommend investing in an inexpensive Intel NIC. They go for between $30 and $50 typically (or $450 if you are anything like me and want to jump on the 10GB Ethernet bandwagon).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, as I mentioned above, my resources are *not* maxed out. I installed Samsung Magician (Didn't know about it before so thanks) and my firmware is up to date. I am looking at a decent Intel NIC but my only concern is will it work? When I uninstalled the realtek networking driver, and was completely disconnected from the internet, the lag issue still persisted.

Comment: Try disabling the onboard NIC in the BIOS rather than the OS. See if that clears up any issues. Could be an IRQ problem and cutting the hardware off at the BIOS should fix that... Which brings up another good point. Make sure that your BIOS is up to date.

Comment: Please see my update above. Thanks. All my firmware and software are up to date. I just do not know what to do now, I really hope not to have a $2000 brick.